# Simgrid. How to divide main.c into parts?

Tags: c, simgrid

This is an example of master-worker example. The main.c file consists of three functions and has following structure:

```
#include <simgrid/msg.h>
XBT_LOG_NEW_DEFAULT_CATEGORY(tuto, "all the info and defbug messages of this tutorial");

int master(int argc, char *argv[]){...}
int worker(int argc, char *argv[]){...}
int main(argc, char *argv[]){...}
```

I want to divide `main.c` into three files: `main.c`, `worker.c`, `master.c`. 
But if I will write

`XBT_LOG_NEW_DEFAULT_CATEGORY(tuto, "all the info and debug messages of this tutorial")` in every file it will give an error:

```
multiple definition of `_simgrid_log_category__tuto__constructor__'
```

If I will define it only once I can't use `XBT_INFO` in other files.
How to avoid it?

Comment: If the creators of this library were sane, they'd make it so that you use the `#include` in all three `.c` files, but you only use the macro `XBT_LOG_`... in one. It shouldn't matter which. The variables it defines should be *declared* in the header, and *defined* by the macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XBT_LOG_NEW_DEFAULT_CATEGORY(tuto, "...")` defines a logging category so you should only use it in one `.c` file. You can declare (and use) this category in another file with:

```
XBT_LOG_EXTERNAL_DEFAULT_CATEGORY(tuto);
```

Once you have called one of those macros in a file, you can use `XBT_INFO(...)` and friends in this file.

Comment: Once I called XBT_LOG_EXTERNAL_DEFAULT_CATEGORY in a file, I can't use XBT_INFO in other file in the same directory. How can I solve it?

Comment: You have to use XBT_LOG_EXTERNAL_DEFAULT_CATEGORY (or XBT_LOG_NEW_DEFAULT_CATEGORY) in **each** file where you're using XBT_INFO. And must use XBT_LOG_NEW_DEFAULT_CATEGORY exactly once (per log name).